# Proper PTR record

Tags: centos, postfix

I have a dedicated server with Plesk Panel 11.5 to handle the clients' sites and the next specs:

- IP 1: mydomain.tld
- IP 2: myclient1.tld, myclient2.tld, myclientX.tld

The hostname is sv01.mydomain.tld. The problem come when my clients send a mail through postfix. I don't know how to properly configure the DNS (or Postfix in case the problem is there). As you can imagine, the reverse is not working.

IP 1 resolves to sv01.domain.tld but I don't know what to do with the IP 2.

Should I create a mail.mydomain.tld and configure something in the DNS zone of the clients (MX(10) mail.mydomain.tld instead of mail.myclient1.tld).

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2):

The reverse `PTR` record is only of interest (potentially, depending on the policy of the receiving party) for outbound mail.

The `MX` records, on the other hand, are specific to inbound mail and will not affect the scenario from the question.

To avoid unnecessary complexity I think you may want to configure your MTA to only use one of the addresses.

IP 1 may be the most convenient as it sounds like you already have things properly set up for this address. However, it would probably be a good idea to set up a reverse entry for IP 2 as well, just to have it in place for any other situation that may need it.

Make sure that the reverse entries are *forward confirmed* (ie, have matching `A`/`AAAA` records) and if possible configure your MTA to identify itself by the same name as in the reverse entry.

Regarding the `MX` records it would probably be more convenient to have them all refer to a single name but, as mentioned above, that is really a separate concern.

Answer (score 2):

Usually MTA checks if PTR is equal to the A record of the hostname.
So your PTR should match the hostname your MTA provides in EHLO message (usually it's a server's hostname) and that hostname should be resolved via A record back to the same IP.

But that is not very strict as far as i know. RFC only specifies that "Every Internet-reachable host should have a name".

So you may specify any or a hostname.

Answer (score 0):

1. As far as I've seen Plesk handles the configuration for which IP address mail originates from on a per-domain basis for you out-of-the-box. It is about the only good thing that Plesk does, don't worry about it.
2. MTAs will validate your connection using Forward-Confirmed Reverse DNS [FCrDNS]. It does this by:

   1. Looking up the PTR record for the IP used to connect.
      eg: `4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR mail.foo.com`
   2. Looking up the A record for the hostname returned
      eg: `mail.foo.com. IN A 1.2.3.4`
   3. Checking that the forward record retrieved by the reverse lookup matches the IP address that your server is connecting from.

   *Most* MTAs generally won't care what hostname you advertise in your `HELO`, only that FCrDNS passes.

Other DNS-related concerns:

- Some MTAs will not accept mail from domains that do not have a default A record.
  eg: `foo.com. IN A 1.2.3.4`
- Some MTAs will not accept mail from domains without valid MX records.